# "The input is not a valid Base-64 string" Error

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, http

The following ajax call fails with this message: "The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the padding characters. "

```
getData: function (url, callback, errorCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: ServiceHelper.GetCombinedURL(url),
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {

            if (data.ResponseType != 'SUCCESS') {
                viewModels.Main.busyMessage(undefined);
                viewModels.Main.message(data.Message);
                if (errorCallback != null) errorCallback();
            } else {
                if (callback != null) callback(data);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, e, s) {

            if (xhr.readyState != 4)
                return;
            viewModels.Main.busyMessage(undefined);
            viewModels.Main.message('Error occured. Please contact administrator for assistance.');
            if (errorCallback != null) errorCallback();
        }
    });
},
```

This is the url for the ajax call:

```
http://localhost/TMO.SA.GenTrac.Web/Services?redirectURL=devwsnweb001/services/GenTracService/REST/GeneratorDetail/Ref/GeneratorStatus
```

This worked a week ago. I get back from vacation, and all of a sudden this is happening. None of the aforementioned code has changed. The success function is called, by the way. What could cause this?

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't appear to do anything related to Base64 decoding, so your error is probably coming from elsewhere. The stack trace will tell you the exact line and file where the error is occurring (assuming this is a JavaScript error and the error message isn't something the server is returning).

Comment: It will also be instructive for you to look at the actual response the server is returning. We know nothing about what's running on your server, but it's entirely possible that it's generating the error message but still serving a 2xx (success) response.

Comment: The error message comes from the server. That's the exact message from a .NET exception when trying to decode a malformed base64 string.

Comment: So, perhaps the server, in response to a request for data, is failing when it tries to decode that data? AND, if I call the url directly from the browser, I get: "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed"